# Como calcular el Valor Aproximado en tema de Errores (materia Metodos numericos)

Tags: c#

Hola este es mi primer problema el tema es Estimacion de Errores en la materia de Metodos Numericos
necesito calcular el Valor Aproximado mediante esta formula

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al momento de ejecutarlo el valor que lanza en Valor aproximado no se aproxima al valor real (valor verdadero) en mi interfaz.¿Alguna idea como solucionarlo?

```
public double CalcularValAprox(double x)
    {
        x = Convert.ToInt32(txtBox1.Text);
        double suma = 0;
        double termino;

        for (int i = 0; i < ValT; i++)
        {
            termino = Math.Pow(x, i) / factorial(i);
            suma += termino;
        }
        return suma;
    }
    public static double factorial(int numero)
    {
        double factorial = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= numero; i++)
        {
            factorial *= i;
        }
        return factorial;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Empezaste con el pie izquierdo. Si no muestras que haz hecho un esfuerzo subiendo el código que hiciste no recibirás ayuda. Necesitarás usar ciclos y funciones si quieres, dónde calcules los factoriales. Para las potencias tienes `Math.Pow`.

Comment: Lo siento soy nuevo en esto, no soy experto en la materia pero ya actualice el apartado ;)

Comment: No estas sumando 1